# YA Graphic Novel Five Highschool girls develop powers from toilet water

Tags: story-identification, comics, young-adult

I believe the book starts with a couple of sport/jocks shoving a nerd's head into a toilet in the high school basement in a room that was broken open during renovation.

After his dunking and swirly, the nerd is left to recover, and he accidentally smacks his arm against a wall trying to get up, which gets smashed from super strength.

Yes, there is a super serum floating in the toilet that gives superpowers.

The super strength fades, so the Nerd collects the water in some empty water bottles to study later. Problem is that some of the girls from the local mean girls clique takes his water and drinks it, including the New Girl. The girls all develop superpowers, each one different.

The New Girl develops telepathy and finds out that pretty much everyone in the school is a pervert, with thought bubbles full of pictures of boobs and asses from what people are looking at, which I thought was funny at the time. She doesn't want the clique of Mean Girls to know she has this power, however, and makes friends with the Nerd.

The clique of mean girls develop Shape Shifting, floating/flying, invisibility, and I think, maybe, telekinesis. They use their powers to cheat at school and to steal clothes and things at the mall which gets the cops involved.

As a big plot point near the end of the book the invisible girl is run over and killed while they were screwing around. Everyone panics and much drama is had.

Its eventually found out that all the girls have the same powers but develop at different rates. The fluid in the toilet was supposed to be a super soldier serum but it only permanently works on girls and is constantly mutating. They also have invulnerability and super healing if they get training, so the invisible girl regenerates herself back from the dead at the morgue and is picked up by the government.

The New Girl is given a telepathy blocker which she very much appreciates and all the other girls are put on probation to stop screwing around. They're also given a chance at a job when they graduate.

Not sure what the book looked like, but I had found it on the shelf along with the YA Novel Queen Bee, so I'm pretty sure it's from 2000-2010.

Comment: Your use of the term [toilet water](https://www.beautyanswered.com/what-is-toilet-water.htm) might be confusing.

Comment: They should have drunk Brawndo instead